# Python Pandas: Data Slices

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am stuck with an issue when it comes to taking slices of my data in python (I come from using Matlab).

So here is the code I'm using,

```
import scipy.io as sc
import math as m
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import expm, sinm, cosm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import sys

data = pd.read_excel('DataDMD.xlsx')
print(data.shape)
print(data)
```

The out put looks like so, 
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3H6F.png)

So I wish to take certain rows only (or from my understand in Python slices) of this data matrix. The other problem I have is that the top row of my matrix becomes almost like the titles of the columns instead of actually data points. So I have two problems,

1) I don't need the top of the matrix to have any 'titles' or anything of that sort because it's all numeric and all symbolizes data.

2) I only need to take the 6th row of the whole matrix as a new data matrix.

3) I plan on using matrix multiplication later so is panda allowed or do I need numpy?

So this is what I've tried,

```
data.iloc[0::6,:]
```

this gives me something like this, 
[Output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/578VQ.png)

which is wrong because I don't need the values of 24.8 to be the 'title' but be the first row of the new matrix.

I've also tried using np.array for this but my problem is when I try to using iloc, it says (which makes sense)

> 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'iloc'

If anyone has any ideas, please let me know! Thanks!

Comment: It seems like your issue can be solved with `pd.read_excel('DataDMD.xlsx', header=None)`. Pandas is built on numpy, so you can always get the underlying matrix with `df.values` if the multiplication is far easier in `numpy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid loading the first record as the header, try using the following:

```
pd.read_excel('DataDMD.xlsx', header=None)
```

The `read_excel` function has an **header** argument; the value for the header argument indicates which row of the data should be used as header. It gets a default value of 0. Use **None** as a value for the header argument if none of the rows in your data functions as the header.
There are many useful arguments, all described in [the documentation of the function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html).
This should also help with number 2. 
Hope this helps.
Good luck!